# Popover Placement depending up on space available.

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, fancybox-2

Please have a look at the attached image.

As you can see i am showing a popover. Basically i want to change the placement of the popover depending up on the space available( left or right ). Right now its going outside of an image.

Its a fancy-box(iframe)

[image: popover image]

Showing the popover using this code.

```
  // Position and show the message.
        this.message
            .css({
                left: (tPosition.left + "px"),
                top: ((tPosition.top + t.outerHeight()) + "px")
            })
            .show();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
this.message
     .css({
          left : function () {
               if ( tPosition.left + $(this).width() >= $(this).parent().width() ) {
                   return $(this).parent().width() - $(this).width();
               } 
               else {
                    return tposition.left;
               } 
          },
          top : function () {
            if ( tPosition.top + $(this).height() > $(this).parent().height() ) {
                   return $(this).parent().height() - $(this).height();
               } 
               else {
                    return tposition.top;
               } 
          }
      });
```

Basically you need to check if the popup is going to exceed your containing box boundaries before you show it and adjust it appropriately. On the horizontal axis this is as simple as making sure that mouse position x + the width of the popup is not greater than the width of the parent container. On the vertical axis you want to make sure that mouse position y + the popup height is not greater than the parent container height.

Comment: Still has some issues with the exact position, needs some modification but your answer seems to work so for now I will give an answer +1 .

Comment: what isn't working? if you have margins applied to the popup element then that will mess with things. use jQuery's outerHeight/Width() functions instead.